# R - Converting Hourly Data in "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" format to "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" with as.Date an as.POSIXct not Working

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, timezone

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
timestamp       ave.temperature min.temperature max.temperature
1/10/2017 0:00  27.20604        25.50000        28.54444
1/10/2017 1:00  27.24487        25.70000        28.60682
1/10/2017 2:00  27.26597        25.60667        28.76333
1/10/2017 3:00  27.16104        25.60000        28.32833
```

which I will like to convert the `timestamp` column to the form:

```
timestamp           ave.temperature min.temperature max.temperature
1/10/2017 00:00:00  27.20604        25.50000        28.54444
1/10/2017 01:00:00  27.24487        25.70000        28.60682
1/10/2017 02:00:00  27.26597        25.60667        28.76333
1/10/2017 03:00:00  27.16104        25.60000        28.32833
```

So far I've tried `df$timestamp <- as.Date(df$timestamp, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`, but it returned `NA` values for the `timestamp` column:

```
timestamp       ave.temperature min.temperature max.temperature
NA              27.20604        25.50000        28.54444
NA              27.24487        25.70000        28.60682
NA              27.26597        25.60667        28.76333
NA              27.16104        25.60000        28.32833
```

However, with `df$timestamp <- as.Date(df$timestamp, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`, it becomes:

```
timestamp  ave.temperature min.temperature max.temperature
1/10/2017  27.20604        25.50000        28.54444
1/10/2017  27.24487        25.70000        28.60682
1/10/2017  27.26597        25.60667        28.76333
1/10/2017  27.16104        25.60000        28.32833
```

A this point, I am really clueless as to why this is happening and have not managed to find any similar cases online thus far.. Some insight will be deeply appreciated!

**Remark:** Using `as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")` also results in `NA` for the `timestamp` column.

**Update:** Found solution, but mystery surrouding `as.Date` remains (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I think I may have messed up big time, but I just figured out that the following works:

```
as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

So `df` becomes

```
timestamp           ave.temperature min.temperature max.temperature
1/10/2017 00:00:00  27.20604        25.50000        28.54444
1/10/2017 01:00:00  27.24487        25.70000        28.60682
1/10/2017 02:00:00  27.26597        25.60667        28.76333
1/10/2017 03:00:00  27.16104        25.60000        28.32833
```

as desired. At this point, I still do not understand why the same does not work with `as.Date`. I won't be accepting my answer at this moment, and will welcome any answers which help clarify as to why `df$timestamp <- as.Date(df$timestamp, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")` removed the hourly granularity in the question above, as well as why `df$timestamp <- as.Date(df$timestamp, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")` results in the entire `timestamp` column ending up having `NA` values.. Thanks again!

Comment: This works too `as.Date("1/10/2017 0:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`. `as.Date` will return only date. What is your question ?

Comment: @RonakShah `as.Date("1/10/2017 0:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")` returns `"2017-10-01"`, which is not what I originally wanted (see second dataframe in question above). The desired date format is of the form `"2017-10-01 00:00:00"`. In any case, I believe you have just answered my secondary question on the properties of `as.Date`. Thanks!

Comment: yes, if you need dates use `as.Date`, if you need date-time use `as.POSIXct` or `strptime`.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for the tip :) I'll take note.